# Npm 8 alias package install 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

```
{
   "compute-scroll-into-view-v3": "npm:compute-scroll-into-view@^3.0.3",
}
```

I upgraded NPM to 8, but after installing NPM, the alias function was disabled and 404 was lost.

Hope there's a big shot to solve it

Comment: It seems like this is a bug

Comment: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/6108